# what does "distant" mean in distant supervision?

Tags: nlp, information-extraction, knowledge-base-population

Mentioned in , ACL 09, Mintz et al.

> The distant supervision assumption is that if two
>   entities participate in a relation, any sentence that
>   contain those two entities might express that relation.

Which is easy to understand. But, what does "distant" mean in distant supervision? Or how do we define "distant"?

E.g Given a weekly-supervised training set generalization method that differs from the quoted methed. How do we define is it "distant supervised" or "non-distant supervised"? what is the boundary? I'm recently confused by this.

Comment: The distance is between the annotations and the text. In close (?) supervision (not sure if you can say that – anyway, I mean the "normal" case), annotations are usually attached to a word, phrase, or whatever span they refer to. In distant supervision, annotations are typically at the document level, even though they correspond to units like in the first case. But this correspondence is not expressed.

Comment: This "supervision" in "distance-supervision" has little to do with the "supervised" in "weakly-supervised" =)